# Screen gets stuck on black after installing nvidia-cuda-toolkit and nvidia-cuda-dev

Tags: debian, nvidia, x

I have problem with starting X server on Debian Sid. I have got installed packages `bumblebee-nvidia primus-libs primus-libs:i386`. Screen gets stuck on black when X starts. It's a new problem after installing `nvidia-cuda-dev`, `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and `docker-ce`. System was upgraded between installing and purging NVIDIA CUDA in recovery mode. How can I fix black screen?

`dmesg`: http://paste.asie.pl/sRio

`/var/log/Xorg.1.log`: http://paste.asie.pl/c4K7

Comment: You may try to purge Nvidia drivers and Cuda and start again, making sure you're installing the correct driver version for your specific hardware, the one you should add to the question by [edit]ing it. There's no way to give you a meaningful answer without details.

Comment: I have got GPU hybrid card NVIDIA GTX 950M and Intel HD Graphics 530. I purged NVIDIA drives and installed again. It nothing helps.

Comment: The only version recommended by Nvidia for your card is 390.48 and it shouldn't need additional packages. Bumblebee is no longer used. You can manually install Cuda and that should, theoretically, install the proper driver and all additional requirements including Prime (not Bumblebee). The way to switch cards is via Nvidia X Server Settings.